# python 3.4 spawning process using subprocess causes <defunct>

Tags: python, linux, process, centos, subprocess

I'm trying to write an automated installer, which requires that after I copy some files and change to executable, that I launch a file from '/etc/init.d/'. 
I want the process to continue running even after I have exited the script itself.

Using perl, I did something like this in an older script:

```
`/etc/init.d/sradmin start > /dev/null 2>&1`;
```

This worked well, but I've since moved over to Python and am seeing a lot about subprocess, so I have tried:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/bash', '/etc/init.d/sradmin', 'start'])
```

and get this in my 'ps -ef' output:

```
root      29119  29115  0 20:22 pts/0    00:00:00 [bash] <defunct>
```

In my script it does show the 'starting XXX' so it seems to be launching this but failing.

I've also tried using

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/etc/init.d/sradmin', 'start'])
```

and

```
p = subprocess.Popen('/etc/init.d/sradmin start', shell=True)
```

and

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/etc/init.d/sradmin', 'start'], close_fds=True)
```

I've also tried the stdin, out and error options too.
I have also tried the os.system route but that didn't work (I know it is not recommended but I thought it might work and at least know something else is wrong!).

I'm using CentOS 7 (3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) and running the script as root using Python 3.5.2 (default, Jun 27 2016, 14:02:55)

Are there any dependencies I need to have in place before this will work? Seems a lot of people's recommendations don't seem to work for me.

This one has me stumped. I've only coded in Python for just over a month and usually get to find answers pretty quickly (via stackoverflow or python docs). I've done a lot more advanced stuff than this but yes, I'm still fairly new to Python, so experience is against me!

Many Thanks,

Frank

Comment: have you tried `subprocess.call('/etc/init.d/sradmin start &', shell=True)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've tried this and I'm still getting the 'Starting XXX' message in the script but no process running at all.

Comment: This has been been resolved. The issue was that the file that was executed was corrupt. I replaced it and it's working now, 4 hours later :( I guess it helps to look at the basics before trying to look at the details!